# Having trouble modifying python 2 code to python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I've been trying to translate python 2.7 code to python 3. I believe everything above checkpoint 1 should be correct. But I'm getting an error I associated with the second half. I can always download the file I need straight from the link, but I'd like to know what's breaking here.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import tarfile
import os

path = 'https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz'
url = urlopen(path) 
#checkpoint 1
os.chdir('..')
tfile = tarfile.open(url, "r:gz")
tfile.extractall(".")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "startup.py", line 43, in <module>
    tfile = tarfile.open(url, "r:gz")
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1589, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1636, in gzopen
    fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(name, mode + "b", compresslevel, fileobj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 163, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HTTPResponse
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When confronted with an error like this, closely look at the traceback, and read the documentation for the functions and objects involved.

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns a [`HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) object.

If you look at the error message, you see that [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) expects a `str`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike` object for the parameter `name`.

However, `tarfile.open` supports using a file object as a third argument `fileobj`, and `HTTPResponse` implements the [io.BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) interface. The classes in `io` are basically the file objects that the `open` function returns.

So you should be able to do this:

```
tfile = tarfile.open(None, "r:gz", files)
```

or

```
tarfile.open(fileobj=url, mode="r:gz")
```

The latter could be considered more Pythonic ("explicit is better than implicit").

Comment: Using `tarfile.open(fileobj=url, mode="r:gz")` might be more natural than using positional arguments and including `None` for `name`. I'd also note that the API for `tarfile.open` doesn't seem to have changed between Python 2 and 3, so if the questioner's code worked in Python 2, it was probably only by chance (using the undocumented ability to open names that are actually file-like objects).

Comment: @Blckknght Good suggestion! I've updated my answer. Interesting  (but *weird*) that `open` in python 2 would accept file-like objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
os.chdir('..')
tfile = tarfile.open("enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz", "r:gz")
```

Instead of doing the above two steps, can you just mention the fully qualified file name as parameter to `tarfile.open`? just to rule out the possibility that the path is incorrect

Comment: See edit.. Is this what you were referring to? Because I got another traceback call with this.

Comment: @user10939484 : no.  ```'https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz'``` is a path to a resource on the internet. You need to download it (you can use the linux utility wget or you could just save it from your browser). Once downloaded you need to specify this path(the full path i.e /home/user/enron_mail.tar.gz instead of just the relative path ) as parameter to ```tarfile.open```